# How do I display menu of an application using shortcut

Tags: unity, 13.04

How do I display menu of an application using keyboard shortcut?

E.g. in LibreOffice Calc I'm used to use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to display menu File or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to display window files. But these shortcuts are not working and I have to use mouse to hover over the top bar, wait till the menu appear and click - what an annoying process.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: 'Alt+...' is working like a charm for me. Maybe you want to see [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: OK, I can report a bug, I just want to be sure it cannot be enabled somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you press and hold the Super/Windows key you can see a list of shortcuts (in Ubuntu with Unity).
One of them is the one you are looking for:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> : Opens the first menu or, if there is no menu, it opens the first indicator (in the top right corner). When this shortcut doesn't work, try just <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Alt + F10 works, but it is not the way I prefer.